# Is the Schrodinger equation true for any operator?

Tags: schroedinger-equation

I am going to use the notation $\hat{u}$ to refer to the operator version of $u$.

For energy, E, and position $\hat{x}$. If we have a closed system and energy does not change over time:

$$ E \hat{x} = \hat{E} \circ \hat{x} $$

because since energy is constant it cannot have different complex probabilities.

but this works for a variety of operators and so we can have

$$ E \hat{x} = \hat{H} \circ \hat{x} $$

for any Hamiltonian.

Suppose that

$$ \hat{x} \circ \hat{f} = \hat{p} $$

than

$$ E \hat{x} \circ \hat{f} = E \hat{p} = \hat{H} \circ \hat{p}$$

Is it true that:

$$ \forall \hat{u}. \, E \hat{u} = \hat{H} \circ \hat{u} $$

So, the Schrodinger equaton has nothing to do with the position wave function but rather with a general property of energy and position is just nice and convenient for doing calculations?

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Nowhere have you written the schrodinger equation ($i \hbar d\psi(x,t)/dt =\hat{H}\psi(x,t)$), unless you did so in some non-standard notation.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to go around replacing operators by their eigenvalues...this is only true if the operator is assumed to be acting on its eigenvector. Either way, it would be wise to remember that these operators don't necessarily commute.

Answer (score 1):

In one of your preceding statements $$E\hat{x}=\hat{H}\hat{x}$$ you forgot an important caveat: this is only true for eigenfunctions of both $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{x}$. Schrodinger's equation guarantees our wavefunction $\psi$ to be an eigenfunction of $\hat{H}$, but **only** that function is guaranteed.

So $$E\hat{u}=\hat{H}\hat{u}$$

will not be true for all $\hat{u}$. Only for those whose eigenfunctions are $\psi$ will it be true.